# Saltstack exclude specific minions from run from reactor

Tags: salt-stack

I should exclude some sls from run

I use reactor to apply highstate when minions starts up, like this:

`/etc/salt/master.d/reactor/start.sls:`

```py
reactor:                            # Master config section "reactor"                                                                                  
  - 'salt/minion/*/start':          # Match tag "salt/minion/*/start"
    - /srv/salt/reactor/start.sls        # Things to do when a minion starts
```

`/srv/salt/reactor/start.sls:`

```py
highstate_run:
  local.state.apply:
    - tgt: {{ data['id'] }}
```

It works. But how to exclude some hosts e.g by name ?

I tried to use compounds in sub sls files. But unfortunately excluding in sls files does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [jinja][1] for this.
For a simple example, if you want to exclude minion names that start with 'region1', you can do

````
{% if not data['id'].startswith('region1') %}
highstate_run:
  local.state.apply:
    - tgt: {{ data['id'] }}
{% endif %}```


  [1]: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html
````